# How merge two matrix with same size in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrix with same size. I'd like to merge them.

Input matrix A:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  0  5  8  1  0  0
2  5  0  2  4  0  0
3  8  2  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Input matrix B:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  0  0  0  1  2  0
2  0  0  0  4  3  0
3  0  0  0  2  0  0
4  1  4  2  0  0  0
5  2  3  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The result should be like this:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  0  5  8  1  2  0
2  5  0  2  4  3  0
3  8  2  0  2  0  0
4  1  4  2  0  0  0
5  2  3  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I find many questions about merging two matrix with different size, but few ones about same size matrix. The matrix are symmetric with 0 on diagonal. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: `A + B`? Will one matrix always have information missing from the other matrix? Will the missing information always be zero?

Comment: If the zero case is true, so the answer is A+B as  @AA5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. One matrix may have overlapped information from the other matrix. The missing information is always zero. The matrix should be like the ones updated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the 0 indices in matrix `A` and replace the corresponding elements from `B`.

```
inds <- A == 0
A[inds] <- B[inds]
A

#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  0  5  8  1  2
#2  5  0  2  4  3
#3  8  2  0  2  5
#4  1  4  2  0  3
#5  2  3  5  3  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the expected result, you may also be able to use either `pmax()` or `ifelse()`:

```
pmax(mat1, mat2)

     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  0  5  8  1  2
[2,]  5  0  2  4  3
[3,]  8  2  0  2  5
[4,]  1  4  2  0  3
[5,]  2  3  5  3  0

ifelse(mat1 == 0, mat2, mat1)

     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  0  5  8  1  2
[2,]  5  0  2  4  3
[3,]  8  2  0  2  5
[4,]  1  4  2  0  3
[5,]  2  3  5  3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.

First, find the zeroes in the `lower.tri` part of the matrix, and replace those with values from matrix B.

```
A[a == 0 & lower.tri(A)] <- B[A == 0 & lower.tri(A)]
A
#      v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
# [1,]  0  5  8  0  0
# [2,]  5  0  2  0  0
# [3,]  8  2  0  0  0
# [4,]  1  4  2  0  0
# [5,]  2  3  5  3  0
```

Next, replace the `upper.tri` with the `lower.tri`. You need `t()` to put the values in the correct place.

```
A[upper.tri(A)] <- t(A)[upper.tri(A)]
A
#      v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
# [1,]  0  5  8  1  2
# [2,]  5  0  2  4  3
# [3,]  8  2  0  2  5
# [4,]  1  4  2  0  3
# [5,]  2  3  5  3  0
```

Though it seems like you could also just do `A + B` -- it's not exactly clear what you mean by "merge" in your question...